# Single Background Process when using Blazor and Signal R

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, blazor, background-process

I plan to develop a new application that has multiple users running a webpage who need to be notified of occasional changes in a SQL database.  The database is hosted elsewhere and I will not be allowed triggers therefore plan to poll for changes I need to push to users (thinking I will use Signal R for the push).  I am new to Blazor and Signal R and wonder whether the single background task that does the polling should simply be a completely separate background windows process or should I be incorporating it into my Blazor solution?  I have not written a Blazor application before so if the question is off-base for this technology, happy to have any direction offered.

Comment: Polling is never good I try to avoid it as much as possible. You can create a service on the API that injects `IHubContext<NameOfHubClass>` into it. The service can then broadcast to clients from the server. With this service you can notify clients of any `Post`, `Put` or `Delete` requests. They can then decide if they need to hit the api to get updated data. If you dont have access to the API create a self hosted app and proxy to it.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since this question was asked, but as I came across this some time ago, and realised how easy the answer is, I thought I'd post it in case it helps.

If you're using Blazor server-side, then SignalR comes for free. You can add a static class to your code, and use that as a message broker to notify all clients that something has happened.

I'm not in front of my PC now, so can't add too much code here, but if you look at the (rather rambling) [blog post I wrote about it](https://www.pixata.co.uk/2021/12/22/mvvm-style-messaging-in-blazor/), it should be clear enough. Read right to the end, as it's the SignalR paragraph there that is what you want.

I've done this in a few projects, and it works really well, for almost no code.